# R: remove relative differences more than a certain amount

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that takes a sequence and removes any relative jump between consecutive numbers more than a given amount (here, 13). Of the two consecutive numbers, it should delete the number which is further from the median of the whole sequence.

My current function passes the first 3 tests, but not the 4th, where the number which jumps is at the end, because the for loop index doesn't reach that far.

I wonder if there is a better approach in general?

```
abs.dif <- function(v) {
  abs(diff(v))
}

remove.semitones.bigger.than <- function(v, semitone_distance = 13) {

  # how many above the st distance will there be?
  v_dif <- abs.dif(v)
  
  # predetermine how many will violate the condition, so that the index counter will not go too far after deleting from the vector
  no_above <- sum(as.numeric(v_dif > semitone_distance))

  median_v <- median(v)
  
  no_seq <- 1:((length(v)-1)-no_above)

  for (i in no_seq) {

    abs_dif <- abs.dif(c(v[i], v[i+1]))

    if(abs_dif > 13) {
      # which is further from the median? delete that one
      if(abs.dif(c(median_v, v[i])) > abs.dif(c(median_v, v[i+1])) ) {
        v <- v[-i]
      }
      else {
        v <- v[-(i+1)]
      }
    }


  }
  v
}


# tests
remove.semitones.bigger.than(c(51, 55, 58, 51, 63))
remove.semitones.bigger.than(c(51, 55, 78, 58, 51, 63))
remove.semitones.bigger.than(c(78, 55, 58, 51, 63))
remove.semitones.bigger.than(c(51, 55, 58, 51, 78))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little bit at the end to check the last two alone seems to work, but I am not sure this is the most elegant solution:

```
remove.semitones.bigger.than <- function(v, semitone_distance = 13) {

  # how many above the st distance will there be?
  v_dif <- abs.dif(v)

  # predetermine how many will violate the condition, so that the index counter will not go too far after deleting from the vector
  no_above <- sum(as.numeric(v_dif > semitone_distance))

  median_v <- median(v)

  no_seq <- 2:((length(v))-no_above)

  for (i in no_seq) {

    abs_dif <- abs.dif(c(v[i-1], v[i]))

    if(abs_dif > 13) {
      # which is further from the median? delete that one
      if(abs.dif(c(median_v, v[i-1])) > abs.dif(c(median_v, v[i])) ) {
        v <- v[-(i-1)]
      }
      else {
        v <- v[-(i)]
      }
    }

  }
  # separately check the last 2

  if(abs.dif(c(v[length(v)], v[length(v)-1])) > 13) {
    if(abs.dif(c(median_v, v[length(v)-1])) > abs.dif(c(median_v, v[length(v)])) ) {
      v <- v[-(length(v)-1)]
    }
    else {
      v <- v[-length(v)]
    }
  }

  v
}
```